# Is there a way for me to add an exception to my code? (CLOSED)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have this code:

```
x=1
while x <= 2:
    text=input("> ")
    print(f"running {text}....")
    x=x+0
    if text=="quit":
        quit()
    if text=="clear":
        import os
        os.system("clear")
```

So i wanted to know if there was a way for me to tell python "hey could you please not print "running..." on these two words, clear and quit?" And well i tried all i could think of, and it either: ignored it, or it threw up an error telling me to screw off, could you guys maybe help me?

Comment: Python parsers don't tell you to screw off. They give messages pinpointing at what is wrong, which you should use to make corrections.

Comment: @trincot i know i was just trying to be a little more fun with the description haha

Comment: What do you try to achieve with `x=x+0`?

Comment: So funny. Now maybe you could edit your question and show which variant you tried with and what the error message really was.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't reply, so, it kinda sounds unbelievable, i forgot what i had tried, i have terrible memory, sorry once again! @trincot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty similar to fizzbuzz. That's probably why it seems hard to come up with a "nice" solution.

```
text=input("> ")
if text != "quit" && text != "clear":
    print(f"running {text}....")
```

I was just about to add an alternative and better approach with `elif` and `else`, but @milanbalazs was faster. :)

When you expand the application, this approach might be a good option:

```
nonprintables = ["quit", "clear"]
while x <= 2:
    text=input("> ")
    if not text in printables:
        print(f"running {text}....")
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying, i tried the first method, thanks!! I appreciate you and everyone else who contributed

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Perhaps the easiest way to use the `if/elif/else` in your code.

**Code:**

```
x = 1
while x <= 2:
    text = input("> ")
    x = x + 0
    if text == "quit":
        quit()
    elif text == "clear":
        import os
        os.system("clear")
    else:
        print(f"running {text}....")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 

> foo
running foo....
> quit
```

Comment: I believe this is the better option for the asker's use case.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Low effort and it's understandable change.